# Get import text file mod time with SQL Enterprise Manager DTS

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, import, dts

I am using the Data Transformation Service (DTS) functions or SQL Enterprise Manager 2000 to run a scheduled import of a text file dump from a legacy system into the database.

I am already doing some transformations with VBS as part of the import to handle some inconsistencies in the text file dump. Most of transformation script is automatically generated and looks something like this:

```
****************************************
' Visual Basic Transformation Script
' Copy each source column to the 
' destination column
****************************************

Function Main()

    DTSDestination("db_column_title1") = DTSSource("txt_column_title1")
    DTSDestination("db_column_title2") = DTSSource("txt_column_title2")
    DTSDestination("db_column_title3") = DTSSource("txt_column_title3")
    DTSDestination("db_column_title4") = DTSSource("txt_column_title4")
    Main = DTSTransformStat_OK

End Function
```

I would like to include the last mod time of the text file as an additional column in the database. I have already created the column in the database table `import_date` but I do not know how to get a reference to the text file's last mod time into this VBScript.

Basically I want to add something like this:

```
DTSDestination("import_date") = DTSSource.LastModTime
```

I've tried googling for a property like this but I haven't found anything, VBS and DTS are still pretty vague to me so I am not sure if it is even possible to get the text file mod time as a reference into the script.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use ActiveX scripting objects in the generated transformation script, this allows me to get a direct reference to the imported text file. I can read the mod time form that instead of trying to find a ModTime property for `DTSSource`:

```
****************************************
' Visual Basic Transformation Script
' Copy each source column to the 
' destination column
****************************************

Function Main()

    // create a direct reference to the import file
    Dim oFSO
    Dim importFile

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set importFile = oFSO.GetFile("\\server\file\path")

    // get mod time from the reference
    lastMod = importFile.DateLastModified

    DTSDestination("db_column_title1") = DTSSource("txt_column_title1")
    DTSDestination("db_column_title2") = DTSSource("txt_column_title2")
    DTSDestination("db_column_title3") = DTSSource("txt_column_title3")
    DTSDestination("db_column_title4") = DTSSource("txt_column_title4")

    // add the data here
    DTSDestination("import_date") = lastMod

    Main = DTSTransformStat_OK

End Function
```